# How to hide/remove specific category title from all woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories

I want to hide title of a specific category from visitors in woocoomerce pages?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean delete the category ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the title of category page title, You can you `woocommerce_show_page_title` conditionally to remove the title from page.If you will be more specific what you want to achieve  I can help you in a better way.